# JXTitledPanel gradient effect

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, swingx, substance

I'm using the SwingX JXTitledPanel and I'd like to have a gradient effect as shown in the SwingX demo.

My current understanding is that it is up to the Look & Feel manager (I'm using Insubstance) to decide if any gradient should be applied.

Is this correct? Any workaround to force a gradient effect in the background of the title?

Many thanks,
Thomas